# vs code IntelliSense not working with webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a simple webpack config .

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

After I build and upload my modules to npm and use them on other projects the **vs code** IntelliSense is not working for these modules. The module functions are documented with **jsdoc**.

```
import { myFunc } from 'myModule';
```

Or

```
const myModule = require('myModule');
```

Myfunc and myModule have no IntelliSense auto complate support or any other.

How can I keep the jsdoc working after webpack build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package is coming through npm, you need to publish a type definition file (`.d.ts`). `d.ts` files contain type definitions and comments for your API that allow us to efficiently provide rich intellisense for external packages. VS Code is limited in how it can parse the actual JS code from `node_modules` packages.

Here's some resources on getting started with `d.ts` files:

- Overview of how VSCode's JS intellisense works: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense
- Writing and publishing a d.ts files: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Comment: What if my code does not use typescript? I do not get how this is supposed to work.

Comment: You can  use `d.ts` files with JavaScript project too. Check out the links in the answer for more info