# VScode intellisense not working when importing from package bundled with webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, visual-studio-code, package

So I've been creating my own npm package and using webpack to bundle the code into one file.
I've seen similar questions asked before such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591844/vs-code-intellisense-not-working-with-webpack-bundles).

[Packages index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC5GR.png)
When I bundle this code using webpack and set the package.json "main" to the compiled code,I dont get any intellisense when importing ([no intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qda0S.png)).
However when setting the package.json "main" to the index.js and importing the package I get intellisense ([intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIe6S.png)).

My questions are:

1. What are the possible fixes?
2. Is there an easy way to fix this without declaring the types of each function that is exported (possibly a setting in webpack.config.js)?
3. If there is no easy way to fix this is there a bundler that does this automatically that I can switch to.

Comment: Also I'm just using npm link to link the test package at this point, but I have published this and had the same problem

Comment: I've resolved this problem by taking webpack out of the equation entirely and just transpiling my package using @babel/cli into a dist folder, this way I get intellisense and I don't have to work with webpack.